# General ODBC Error for large table on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to fetch data from my vertica tables.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
         With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DSN=Vertica;" _
        , Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)).QueryTable
'        .CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array( _
     "Select SalesID, Revenue from Table")
        

        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name = "tablename"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

However the code is throwing a "General ODBC Error" at line

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

My hunch is that this is happening because the table has 150k rows.
But I cannot compromise on this and I need all 150k rows. What can I do here? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it work for a limited query `Select SalesID, Revenue from Table LIMIT 10000` ?

Comment: huh, its not working for that either @CDP1802

Comment: Does it work for an eve more limited query? (i.e. Just 10 records ?)

Comment: What kind of database is the data coming from? What did you try to get this working?

Comment: Tried with limit 5. Its still not working :|

Answer (score 0):

Test the connection with

```vb
Sub TestConnect()
    Dim conn, i As Integer, s As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open "DSN=Vertica;"
    For i = 0 To conn.Errors.Count - 1
        s = s & conn.Errors(i) & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: I did.
It says: 2567: Canonical locale: en_US, standard olation: LEN_KBINARY

Comment: @pri Mar Add `MsgBox conn.Execute("SELECT count(*) FROM Table")(0)` and run again

Comment: It showing
170198837 in the message box

Comment: @Pri Mar That's 170+ million rows, is that correct ?

Comment: Yup, its 170m rows.